# Electron: add frame on frameless window child

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I am working on a `frameless` and `fullscreen` Electron App.I am initializing a browser window with the following configuration:

```
let window = new BrowserWindow({
    resizable: false,
    fullscreen: true,
    minimizable: false,
    frame: false
})
```

This works well unless the app opens a link of a `PDF` file on a `new tab`(which will create a new child window in electron). Since the `BrowserWindow` is `frameless` and `fullscreen`, the `PDF` page is also `fullscreened` and `frameless` thus closing the `child` window hard. One way to close it is using `ALT + f4` or hovering the window on the `taskbar` and clicking `x` after `Alt + tab` on it's preview on `Windows 10`.

Note: since it is frameless, I've added my own controls with the help of the `ipcRenderer` and `ipcMain`. However, this approach is not feasible on `external url of PDFs`.

I am using `Electron ^12.0.1`.

Is there a way to instruct electron to add the default controls on all child windows but still make the main `BrowserWindow` frameless ?

Comment: I'm struggling with exactly same issue. Did you find any solution to this?

Comment: @Kepaa as a workaround, I embedded the PDFs on my application's page rather than opening it